# Reduce pre-allocated disk space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, shrink

We have a reporting SQL (2014 R2 Enterprise) system with a Reporting and Staging DB on it. The reporting DB is pre-provisioned at 4 TB across 8 data files. Currently it contains just shy of 1 TB of data and growth is marginally slow.

We need to reclaim 2 TB of that pre-allocated space on the SAN...

Since the data files are pre-grown, I assume I need to just change the file initial size and then perform a shrinkdb operation. I know the concerns and issues involved in a shrinkdb, and I just reviewed the article written by @BrentOzar (https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/) about it.

Given the pre-allocated file size versus the actual usage, should I be less worried about the fragmentation consequences?

On a side note: I love the tag descriptor when entering 'Shrink' as a tag...

Comment: Is the data spread across all 8 files or is it all in 1 of them?

Comment: I would definitely shrink the files instead of the database. Regarding fragmentation, we don't know how fragmented your indexes are currently, or if fragmentation even matters in your environment.  Brent has a few blogs and videos about this too. [Here's one](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/why-index-fragmentation-doesnt-matter-video/) and here is a post about [internal and external fragmentation](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/) with notes on fill factor, etc.

Comment: @sqldavedb it's spread out. each file is ~534gb with 126gb of space used. (76% free)

Comment: I should note, it's all on flash storage.

Comment: Have you tried shrink file with truncate only? Will avoid any page movement

Comment: @sqldavedb Yep. Tried it and it freed up almost no space in PRD... Looks like I need to, incrementally, do a shrinkfile on each file.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, as some have suggested, our only option was to incrementally shrink files w/out truncate only. The cost/benefit didn't really work out, so we are living with what we have.

Thank you all for the help and suggestions.